# Use regex to extract mixed fraction and text that may also contain mixed fractions with R (stringr)

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Please see below for a sample of the data I am working with, I have 100K+ entries in total, however.

**note that the `...` in the comment** under `UNIT` is just to make it fit.  For example, the full `UNIT` text is for the first item is `4- to 5-mm-diameter` and the fifth item is `3 1/2- to 4-inch-diameter`, etc.

```
library(tidyverse)
                                                #i QTY    UNIT
parts <- c("6 4- to 5-mm-diameter plugs",       #1  6     4- to...diameter
           "6 large bricks",                    #2  6     large
           "1 1/3 shipment concrete",           #3  1.33  shipment
           "1 (14- to 15-oz) gold bars",        #4  1     (14- to 15-oz)
           "16 3 1/2- to 4-inch-diameter caps", #5  16    3 1/2- to...eter
           "1 1/2 tons sand",                   #6  1.5   tons
           "2 1 1/4- to 3-inch diameter caps",  #7  2     1 1/4- to...eter      
           "1/3 shipment cement")               #8  .333  shipment
```

I've had some moderate success working from some of the answers on SO but I run into problems when the `UNIT` text *also* contains mixed fractions as in items 1 and 5:

```
# Goal: extract QTY as mixed frac
parts %>% 
  str_extract("(\\d+[\\/\\d[ ]?]*|\\d*)")

# i=1, 5 broken
#[1] "6 4"      "6 "       "1 1/3 "   "1 "       "16 3 1/2" "1 1/2 "  

# Goal: extract UNIT word
parts %>% 
  str_extract("[[:graph:]]{3,11}|[- to ].{5,21}")

# all i with some problem  
# [1] " 4- to 5-mm-diameter p" " large bricks"          " 1/3 shipment concrete"
# [4] " (14- to 15-oz) gold b" " 3 1/2- to 4-inch-diam" " 1/2 tons sand"
```

My goals is to extract `QTY` and `UNIT` as shown in the comment of the code from first to last entry as `6, 6, 1 1/3, 1, 16, 1, 2, 1/3` - in addition, I am trying to pull out the text under `UNIT` abbreviated just so it'd fit in the code section - here it is in full: `4- to 5-mm-diameter, large, shipment, (14- to 15-oz), 3 1/2- to 4-inch-diameter, tons,  1 1/4- to 3-inch diameter, shipment`.

My intuition suggests I should do this in two steps but please let me know if there are better ways to achieve this.

Thank you.

edit: added a critical example number 8.

Comment: I assumed that the answer to either in isolation may not solve it i.e. solutions for `QTY` do not account for solutions for strings like the `UNIT` in my example.

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/pqbBC5, does it work for you?

Comment: I added an additional item to the list, #8, that I had not previously.

Comment: Any more additions planned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```r
m <- str_match(parts, '^(\\d+(?:\\s+\\d+/\\d+)?|\\d+/\\d+)\\s+((?:\\d+(?:-?in(?:ch)?|")?\\s+)*\\S+(?:\\s+to\\s+(?:\\d+(?:-?in(?:ch)?|")?\\s+)*\\S+)?)')
qty <- m[,2]
# => [1] "6"     "6"     "1 1/3" "1"     "16"    "1 1/2" "2"     "1/3"  
unit <- m[,3]
# => [1] "4- to 5-mm-diameter"       "large"                    
#    [3] "shipment"                  "(14- to 15-oz)"           
#    [5] "3 1/2- to 4-inch-diameter" "tons"                     
#    [7] "1 1/4- to 3-inch diameter" "shipment"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/332zju) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iEKcpg/3). **Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+(?:\s+\d+/\d+)?|\d+/\d+)` - Group 1 (`m[,2]`): one or more digits followed with an optional occurrence of one or more whitespaces, one or more digits, `/` and one or more digits, or a `/` enclosed with one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `((?:\d+(?:-?in(?:ch)?|")?\s+)*\S+(?:\s+to\s+(?:\d+(?:-?in(?:ch)?|")?\s+)*\S+)?)` - Group 2 (`m[,3]`):

  - `(?:\d+(?:-?in(?:ch)?|")?\s+)*` - zero or more occurrences of one or more digits followed with an optional occurrence of a `"` or an optional `-`, `in` and then an optional `ch` substring and then one or more whitespaces
  - `\S+` - one or more chars other than whitespace (a "word")
  - `(?:\s+to\s+(?:\d+(?:-?in(?:ch)?|")?\s+)*\S+)?` - an optional occurrence of:

    - `\s+to\s+` - `to` enclosed with one or more whitespaces
    - `(?:\d+(?:-?in(?:ch)?|")?\s+)*` - see above
    - `\S+` - one or more chars other than whitespace.

Comment: Thank you for this outstanding answer.